# Loop in Sql query (While , For)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for `Users` and another for `Role` and a table between them `Access`

How can I add a role to all of users in a SQL query?

Table `User`:

```
ID  Name ...
1
5
9
10
11
```

Table `Role` :

```
Id ....
10
11
12
```

Table `Access`:

```
UserID    RoleID
1           10
2           10
3           10
4           10
```

I want to do it with Loop, means from row 1 of User to end

Update :

I am using:

```
DECLARE @roleId int

SET @roleId = 79

INSERT INTO Access (Users.code, @roleId)
   SELECT code, @roleId 
   FROM Users
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@roleId'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @roleId ...;

INSERT INTO Access (UserID, RoleID)
SELECT ID, @roleId
FROM Users
```

Then you could also add a where if you wanted to. It doesn't sound like you want to so I won't give an example, but you can imagine how this query could be expand to do more complicated things.

If you've got the appropriate unique key, you might want to do something like:

```
DECLARE @roleId ...;

INSERT INTO Access (UserID, RoleID)
SELECT ID, @roleId
    FROM Users
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Access WHERE RoleID = @roleId)
```

You could also add a user to all roles by switching it around and doing something like:

```
DECLARE @userId ...;

INSERT INTO Access (UserID, RoleID)
SELECT @userId, ID
FROM Roles
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in your `...Access (Users.code,...)`. That's a syntax error.

Comment: Just use `INSERT INTO Access (UserID, ...` as I said in my answer. Don't specify `Users.code`.

Comment: @user3780058 have you resolved your problem? I see this is still in the unanswered queue. Please accept my answer if it helped you, and if it hasn't then I'd love to continue to help.